# How to look up specific indices of vectors in a list of vectors, where the indices are given in a vector? (without a for loop)

Tags: r, list, performance, lookup

I would like to find an efficient operation to do the following look up in a list:

```
L = list(10:15,11:20)
a = c(3,7)
b = numeric()
for(i in 1:length(a)) b[i] = L[[i]][a[i]]
```

I think `for` loops are inefficient and I imagine this can be done faster using, for example, `sapply`. My main goal is to do this efficiently when `L` is long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

Your aversion to a `for` loop may be unfounded. I've found that it can be very machine dependent.  On my current machine, with `b` properly initialized, a base R `for` loop is slower only than an `Rcpp` solution, and that just barely. See the updated benchmark below. The `loop1` solution is properly initialized. However, I've tried this on other machines, and on some the `for` loops are indeed slower than the `apply` solutions.

---

A base R vectorized solution using `unlist`, `cumsum`, and `lengths`:

```
b <- unlist(L)[a + c(0, cumsum(lengths(L)[1:(length(L) - 1L)]))]
```

Benchmarking (tossing in an `Rcpp` solution)*

```
library(purrr)

L <- lapply(sample(4:10, 1e5, TRUE), seq)
a <- sapply(lengths(L), function(x) sample(x, 1))

Rcpp::cppFunction("IntegerVector ListIndex(const List& L, const IntegerVector& a) {
const int n = a.size();
IntegerVector b (n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) b(i) = as<IntegerVector>(L[i])(a(i) - 1);
return b;
}")
    
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sapply = sapply(1:length(a), function(x) L[[x]][a[x]]),
                           vapply = vapply(seq_along(L), function(i) L[[i]][a[i]], integer(1)),
                           purr = as.integer(imap_dbl(setNames(L, a), ~ .x[as.numeric(.y)])),
                           unlist = unlist(L)[a + c(0, cumsum(lengths(L)[1:(length(L) - 1L)]))],
                           rcpp = ListIndex(L, a),
                           loop1 = {b <- integer(length(a)); for(i in seq_along(a)) b[i] <- L[[i]][a[i]]; b},
                           loop2 = {b <- integer(); for(i in seq_along(a)) b[i] <- L[[i]][a[i]]; b},
                           check = "identical")

#> Unit: milliseconds
#>    expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#> sapply 102.4199 113.72450 125.21764 119.72455 130.41480 291.5465   100
#> vapply  97.8447 107.33390 116.41775 112.33445 119.01680 189.9191   100
#>   purr 226.9039 241.02305 258.34032 246.81175 257.87370 502.3446   100
#> unlist  29.4186  29.97935  32.05529  30.86130  33.02160  44.6751   100
#>   rcpp  22.3468  22.78460  25.47667  23.48495  26.63935  37.2362   100
#>  loop1  25.5240  27.34865  28.94650  28.02920  29.32110  42.9779   100
#>  loop2  41.4726  46.04130  52.58843  51.00240  56.54375  88.3444   100
```

*I couldn't get akrun's `dplyr` solution to work with the larger vector.

Comment: Thks for the efficient solution

Comment: I updated my benchmarking to include a `for` loop solution. I recommend taking a look.

Comment: I am surprised indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Another `apply` method would be `sapply()`.

```
sapply(1:length(a), function(x) L[[x]][a[x]])
[1] 12 17
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
stack(setNames(L, a)) %>%
   group_by(ind) %>% 
   summarise(out = values[[as.numeric(as.character(first(ind)))]]) %>%
   pull(out)
[1] 12 17
```

---

Or in `base R` using `vapply` which would be faster

```
vapply(seq_along(L), \(i) L[[i]][a[i]], numeric(1))
[1] 12 17
```

---

or use `imap` as a compact option

```
library(purrr)
imap_dbl(setNames(L, a), ~ .x[as.numeric(.y)])
 3  7 
12 17
```

Comment: For the `dplyr` solution, I can only get out a vector with max size 10, and those values aren't all correct.

Comment: @jblood94 did you noticed that I used `as.numeric(as.character`

Comment: @jblood94 i.e. if you do that without them, it is a factor column, and then it matches based on the integer coerced value

Comment: Also, i noticed that your big data is having values duplicated, which was not the assumption i used in the dplyr solution

Comment: I tried the code verbatim with and without `as.numeric(as.character`. It might be my R version (4.0.2), but it doesn't work on https://rdrr.io/snippets/ either.

Comment: @jblood94 your sample 'a' have duplicates, i didn't account for that in dplyr code

Comment: Ok. The no duplicate assumption is probably it. Seems an arbitrary assumption, though.

Comment: @jblood94 i didn't thought much at that time about the dupes

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Map` or `mapply`. Since `mapply` can automatically simplify to a vector, we can could use that here to get `b` in one go:

```r
b <- mapply(function(list_members, indices) list_members[indices],
       list_members = L, indices = a, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)

b
#> [1] 12 17
```

Comment: May I ask is there any advantage of using `mapply` over `sapply` (e.g. `sapply(1:length(a), function(x) L[[x]][a[x]])`) in this case?

Comment: Not in this case @benson23. It may be more generalizable, but if the set-up is always as the OP described, I would probably use the simpler `sapply` myself. Of course, it's really just a short hand way of writing the loop, and not necessarily any faster or more efficient.