# Is there any way to improve performance (e.g. vectorize) this look-up and recoding problem implemented by a for loop?

Tags: r, list, performance, for-loop

I need to make recodings to data sets of the following form.

```
# List elements of varying length
set.seed(12345)
n  = 1e3
m  = sample(2:5, n, T)
V = list()
for(i in 1:n) {
  for(j in 1:m[i])  
    if(j ==1) V[[i]] = 0 else V[[i]][j] = V[[i]][j-1] + rexp(1, 1/10) 
  }
```

As an example consider

```
[1]  0.00000 23.23549 30.10976
```

Each list element contains a ascending vector of length m, each starting with 0 and ending somewhere in positive real numbers.

Now, consider a value `s`, where `s` is smaller than the maximum `v_m` of each `V[[i]]`. Also let `v_m_` denote the `m-1`-th element of `V[[i]]`. Our goal is to find all elements of `V[[i]]` that are bounded by `v_m_ - s` and `v_m - s`. In the example above, if `s=5`, the desired vector `v` would be `23.23549`. `v` can contain more elements if the interval encloses more values. As an example consider:

```
> V[[1]]
[1]  0.000000  2.214964  8.455576 10.188048 26.170458
```

If we now let `s=16`, the resulting vector is now `0 2.214964  8.455576`, so that it has `length` 3. The code below implements this procedure using a `for` loop. It returns `v` in a list for all `n`. Note that I also attach the (upper/lower) bound before/after`v`, if the bound lead to a reduction in length of `v` (in other words, if the bound has a positive value).

This loop is too slow in my application because `n` is large and the procedure is part of a larger algorithm that has to be run many times with some parameters changing. Is there a way to obtain the result faster than with a for loop, for example using vectorization? I know `lapply` in general is not faster than `for`.

```
# Series maximum and one below maximum
v_m  = sapply(V, function(x) x[length(x)])
v_m_ = sapply(V, function(x) x[length(x)-1])

# Set some offsets s
s  = runif(n,0,v_m)

# Procedure
d1  = (v_m_ - s)
d2  = (v_m - s)
if(sum(d2 < 0) > 0) stop('s cannot be larger than series maximum.')

# For loop - can this be done faster?
W = list()
for(i in 1:n){
v = V[[i]]
l = length(v)
v = v[v > d1[i]]
if(l > length(v)) v = c(d1[i], v)
l = length(v)
v = v[v < d2[i]]
if(l > length(v)) v = c(v, d2[i])
W[[i]] = v
}
```

Comment: Could you walk through one iteration `i` where the desired result has `length(W[[i]])` of `2`? Based on your text I thought it would be `for(i in 1:n) {
  v = V[[i]];
  W2[[i]] = v[d1[i] < v & v < d2[i]];
}`, but the result doesn't match and I'm having trouble understanding your code in relation to your description.

Comment: @GregorThomas Sry for late reply, I missed your question. I edited the description to give the example you requested.

Comment: The example is for a length 3 vector but I hope it makes things clearer

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try `mapply` like below

```
V <- lapply(m, function(i) c(0, cumsum(rexp(i - 1, 1 / 10))))
v <- sapply(V, tail, 2)
s <- runif(n, 0, v[1, ])
if (sum(v[2, ] < 0) > 0) stop("s cannot be larger than series maximum.")
W <- mapply(
    function(x, lb, ub) c(pmax(lb,0), x[x >= lb & x <= ub], pmin(ub,max(x))),
    V,
    v[1,]-s,
    v[2,]-s
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to *always* append `lb` and `ub` though, and not only when the original series is longer than the selection (see in my code example the `if` condition). The idea here is that `lb` becomes the new lower bound of the selected series, unless `lb` is below zero. `ub` vecomes the new upper bound of the selected series unless `ub` is larger than the upper bound of the full series.

Comment: @tomka Probably you can use `pmin` and `pmax` over `lb` and `ub`, respectively.

Comment: I ran a comparison using `n=1e6` and unfortunately your solution takes about 3 times longer than my initial submit.

Comment: Related, an earlier question on SO of mine on `for` loops vs. `lapply` for `list` operations also found `for` loops to be faster than `mapply` . See accepted answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71694098/how-to-look-up-specific-indices-of-vectors-in-a-list-of-vectors-where-the-indic

Answer (score 1):

I don't think vectorization will be an option since the operation goes from a list of unequal-length vectors to another list of unequal-length vectors.

For example, the following vectorizes all the comparisons, but the `unlist`/`relist` operations are too expensive (not to mention the final `lapply(..., unique)`). Stick with the `for` loop.

```
W <- lapply(
  relist(
    pmax(
      pmin(
        unlist(V),
        rep.int(d2, lengths(V))
      ),
      rep.int(d1, lengths(V))
    ),
    V
  ),
  unique
)
```

I see two things that will give modest gains in speed. First, if `s` is always greater than 0, your final `if` statement will always evaluate to `TRUE`, so it can be skipped, simplifying some of the code. Second is to pre-allocate `W`. These are both implemented in `fRecode2` below. A third thing that gives a slight gain is to avoid multiple reassignments to `v`. This is implemented in `fRecode3` below.

For additional speed, move to `Rcpp`--it will allow the vectors in `W` to be built via a single pass through each vector element in `V` instead of two.

```
set.seed(12345)
n <- 1e3
m <- sample(2:5, n, T)
V <- lapply(m, function(i) c(0, cumsum(rexp(i - 1, 1 / 10))))
v_m <- sapply(V, function(x) x[length(x)])
v_m_ <- sapply(V, function(x) x[length(x)-1])
s <- runif(n,0,v_m)
d1 <- (v_m_ - s)
d2 <- (v_m - s)
if(sum(d2 < 0) > 0) stop('s cannot be larger than series maximum.')

fRecode1 <- function() {
  # original function
  W = list()
  for(i in 1:n){
    v = V[[i]]
    l = length(v)
    v = v[v > d1[i]]
    if(l > length(v)) v = c(d1[i], v)
    l = length(v)
    v = v[v < d2[i]]
    if(l > length(v)) v = c(v, d2[i])
    W[[i]] = v
  }
  W
}

fRecode2 <- function() {
  W <- vector("list", length(V))
  i <- 0L
  for(v in V){
    l <- length(v)
    v <- v[v > d1[i <- i + 1L]]
    if (l > length(v)) v <- c(d1[i], v)
    W[[i]] <- c(v[v < d2[i]], d2[[i]])
  }
  W
}

fRecode3 <- function() {
  W <- vector("list", length(V))
  i <- 0L
  for(v in V){
    idx1 <- sum(v <= d1[i <- i + 1L]) + 1L
    idx2 <- sum(v < d2[i])
    if (idx1 > 1L) {
      if (idx2 >= idx1) {
        W[[i]] <- c(d1[i], v[idx1:idx2], d2[i])
      } else {
        W[[i]] <- c(d1[i], d2[i])
      }
    } else {
      W[[i]] <- c(v[1:idx2], d2[i])
    }
  }
  W
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fRecode1 = fRecode1(),
                               fRecode2 = fRecode2(),
                               fRecode3 = fRecode3(),
                               times = 1e3,
                               check = "equal")
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#>  fRecode1 2.0210 2.20405 2.731124 2.39785 2.80075 12.7946  1000
#>  fRecode2 1.2829 1.43315 1.917761 1.54715 1.88495 51.8183  1000
#>  fRecode3 1.2710 1.38920 1.741597 1.45640 1.76225  5.4515  1000
```

Not a huge speed boost: `fRecode3` shaves just under a microsecond on average for each vector in `V`.

Comment: Thanks (+1 / maybe +25, have to check ;-)) and sorry for late reply, was out of office.

Comment: The `max` of `fRecode2`  is noteworthy. What is going on there?

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://community.rstudio.com/t/large-max-time-for-microbenchmark-of-rcpp-call/102054