# Return specific element of vector in list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of vectors of strings. And I have a vector with indexes. I would like to return the indexed string in each list element.

```
> list = list(c("monday","tuesday","wednesday"),c("thursday","friday","saturday"),"sunday")
> list
[[1]]
[1] "monday"    "tuesday"   "wednesday"

[[2]]
[1] "thursday" "friday"   "saturday"

[[3]]
[1] "sunday"

> vector = c(2,3,1)
> vector
[1] 2 3 1

> goal=c("tuesday","saturday","sunday")
> goal
[1] "tuesday"  "saturday" "sunday"
```

I can get the first element like this:

```
lapply(list,"[[",1)
```

but I cannot index the vector.

I also tried making the vector a list and append it:

```
mapply(append,list,as.list(vector),simplify=F)
```

And I get a list where the last string in each element is a string of the index. But I cannot return the index and use it as a numeric to find the respective string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to look up specific indices of vectors in a list of vectors, where the indices are given in a vector? (without a for loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71694098/how-to-look-up-specific-indices-of-vectors-in-a-list-of-vectors-where-the-indic)

Comment: indeed, this is a similar question. thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure why you are trying to use `append` at all here. Your first approach was essentially correct: Use `[[`. But you need to map over the indices as well as the list, using `mapply`:

```
mapply(`[[`, list, vector)
```

Comment: this is the solution. thank you very much. i was close but you helped me get over the finish line.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the option of using `purrr` from the `tidyverse` collection of packages. The main advantage of using `map_*` instead of `mapply` is the consistent interface between map variants.

```
map2_chr(list, vector, `[[`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
unlist(Map(function(x, i) x[i], list, vector))
[1] "tuesday"  "saturday" "sunday"
```